# Is the use of Action Points permitted in a surprise round?

Tags: dnd-4e

In Dungeons & Dragons 4e can players use an Action Point during a surprise round?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**No**

If you are able to act during a Surprise round<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=318)</sup> you have a couple restrictions:

- You can take one action during a surprise round (minor, move or standard)
- You can take free actions as well with one exception:
- **You cannot spend action points**
- During the surprise round you can take Immediate and Opportunity actions (just not on your own turn)

If you are surprised you:

- Cannot take any actions including immediate and opportunity and free actions.
- Grant Combat Advantage to all attackers for the duration of the surprise round.
- Cannot flank

The full rules are on p267 of the *Player's Handbook* and p190 and p235 of the *Rules Compendium*.

Answer (score 4):

According to page 235 of the Rules Compendium, no. The free action to use an Action Point may only be used during your turn, and not during a surprise round.

Answer (score 2):

No, but for one main reason: using an action point allows you to have an extra action your turn, which contradicts the rule that allows one action per player in a surprise round.